# Как в phpmyadmin, указать внешний ключ?

Tags: php, mysql

Как указать, внешний ключ в phpmyAdmin, просто написать первичный ключ, другой таблицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таблицы должны быть InnoDB.
В структуре таблицы есть внизу ссылка "Связи". Там все находится

Comment: что такое InnoDB?

Comment: движок базы данных

Comment: а что он дает, связь можно же сделать и без этого движка?

Comment: не, нельзя<br>
Гугл в помощь, неужели вы думаете что вас кто-то начнет тут "книгу" писать на тему того что такое БД и как с ней работать?

Comment: на стандартном движке myISAM, есть связи

Comment: движок в свойствах таблицы можно посмотреть в phpMyAdmin